# Call Sitecore controller method from JavaScript (MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I have a controller with a function `ShowEvents(EventCategory eventCategory)`. Is it possible to call this function from client-side JavaScript? I know that I can retrieve items from the database using the [Sitecore.Services.Client (SCC)](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf), but is it possible to actually access methods? Maybe through the controller rendering, if that's possible?

Here is an example of a method I want to call:

```
public class EventListController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowEvents(EventCategory eventCategory)
    {
        var repository = new EventListRepository();
        var eventPages = repository.GetEvents(eventCategory);
        var eventListViewModel = repository.GetEventListViewModel(eventPages);

        return View("/Some/Path/, eventListViewModel);
    }
}
```

This is on Sitecore 7.5 MVC

Answer (score 5):

You can Post to controllers from the client side using the format

`/api/sitecore/{yourcontroller}/{action}` in your case this would be `/api/sitecore/eventlist/showevents` passing the `eventCategory` as the data.

Comment: Perfect ! I've made a custom field in sitecore and I was looking for a way to call a controller method from client side. Using `/api/sitecore/` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can reach every function with

A separate view page named with same name of it and the view pages

will be written with `RAZOR` language which is composed of `c#` and `html`
and surely you  can write `javascript` within the `html` code.
with the `Asp.net` and `MVC5`

here an example :::
 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below format for call the Action method in sitecore project.

Sitecore have own route to manage the action method which is used as API. You can use it for Ajax call from the fronted.

**/api/Sitecore/{controller Name}/{action method name}**

Just post your data as request in data object and cosume the url in above format. It's act like API.